# how to get typeid of incomplete type c++

Tags: c++, types, rtti

I need to store pointers in such a way that later I'll be able to restore it's original type and do some stuff.

```cpp
vector<pair<void*, type_info>> pointers;
```

and later

```cpp
for(auto p : pointers){
   switch(p.second)
      case typeid(sometype):
         DoStuff((sometype*)p.first);
      break; //and so on...
}
```

When I add pointer I naturally do this

```cpp
SomeType* pointer;

pointers.emplace_back((void*)pointer, typeid(SomeType));
```

And it works fine until type is incomplete.
`typeid` is not working with incomplete types so I cannot use it with (for example) `SDL_Texture` from `SDL2` library. But I need somehow differ different types from each other even if part of them is incomplete ones. What to do?

Comment: You might want to look into [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) instead of casting pointers to `void*`, and use `std::any_cast` to restore the original pointer.

Comment: Define an `enum class` that maps to the types you need.

Comment: Is polymorphism out of the question?

Comment: Use typeid of the pointer, rather than typeid of the pointed-to type.

Comment: `typeid(expression)` for polymorphic types wants to return the "real" type - that is why it needs full definition. If this is not what you want - apply @n.'pronouns'm. advice. But the std::any would be the best here, as suggested above

Comment: This is looks like a bad design to be honest. The `typeid` operator is just horrible. You already experience difficulties and it will get worse: the code will get hard to maintain and extend (that switch...). While polymorphism (virtual DoStuff method) seriously solves probably all your problems here. Not to mention you literally reimplement polymorphism here, in a bad way though.

Comment: Btw: in order to use polymorphism with already existing classes, like `SDL_Texture`, all you need to do is to create a wrapper class that accepts `SDL_Texture` as parameter and implements appropriate virtual `DoStuff` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Some examples for your case:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <any>

std::vector<std::any> pointers;
SomeType *pointer;
pointers.emplace_back(std::make_any<SomeType*>(pointer));

/* later on */
for (auto p : pointers) {
    if (SomeType *t = std::any_cast<SomeType*>(p))
        /* p is of type SomeType* */
    else if (...)
        /* check other types */
}
```

Comment: `std::any` is a solution, but I strongly suggest using polymorphism here. With that you get better type safety and you get rid of hard to maintain (and also inefficient) if/else waterfall.